# SpringBoot WebFlux WebClient: Mono and Flux usage

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-webflux

So, I am just getting into WebClient since RestTemplate got a deprecated note.

Things is, I am a bit lost when it comes to requesting and consuming the responses.

At the moment, I am playing around with the Riot Games API for League of Legends. If you check their documentation, you need to send a API key either as a param or a header to consume their services.

As I am trying the WebClient, I am not worrying about abstraction right now, so the current test I have is:

A Builder class, right now I only set the baseUrl and api key:

```
@Service
public class WebClientService {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public WebClient get(String url) {

        return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .defaultHeader("X-Riot-Token", env.getProperty("app.riot.api.key"))
        .build();
    }
}
```

To test, I am making a call to the /summoners endpoint using the below code:

```
@Service
public class SummonerServices {
    @Autowired
    private WebClientService web;

    private String riotEndPoint = "https://br1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/";

    public Flux<Summoners> getSummoner(String summonerName) {

        return web.get(riotEndPoint + summonerName).get()
                .exchange().flatMapMany(e -> e.bodyToMono(Summoners.class));
    }

}
```

I have a controller (omitted because it's not relevant), I call it, and it gets the result as expected.

But I noticed that instead of a `Flux`, I can use a `Mono` like this:

```
public Mono<Summoners> getSummoner(String summonerName) {

    return web.get(riotEndPoint + summonerName).get()
            .exchange().flatMap(e -> e.bodyToMono(Summoners.class));
}
```

What I am failing to understand, by reading the docs and looking at examples on the internet, is when or why to choose one over another?

It seems that for both I can have access to the header response, I have access to the same doOnSucess / doOnError and others methods to treat responses and errors.

They seems pretty much the same, but I they wouldn't just create two exact ways to do the same thing with different names, right? So if anyone could point me to a doc explaining Fux and Mono I would be very glad. Google returned to me pretty much the same tutorials, and they don't explain, they just make use of them.

Comment: what you are looking for is here, webClient is built ontop of project reactor https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/

Comment: and the simple, simple super simple explanation is that a `Flux` is multiple `Mono` you are doing a single rest call and getting one response from their api so you should be using `Mono`. If you on the other hand subscribe to a stream of data, you should be using `Flux`. Both work because a `Flux` can be one or many `Mono`. But you cant subscribe to something using a `Mono` can't be many.